# how to shuffle list in django views.py?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

i'm trying to shuffle a list in django.views

## views.py

```
import random

def all_songs( request):
    songs_list = Songs.objects.all()
    songs_list=random.shuffle(songs_list)
```

but after entering this code the error showing "'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment" shows up. how do i do it without item assignment ?

Answer (score 6):

```
Songs.objects.order_by('?')
```

returns a randomly ordered queryset

see docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields)

Comment: please note that this can be extreamly slow solution on big amounts of rows for some DB backands, for example MySql, fetching rows "as is" and  shuffling in RAM can be march faster.

Answer (score -2):

convert list(here song_list) to list and then shuffle it....

```py
def all_songs( request):
    songs_list = list(Songs.objects.all())
    random.shuffle(songs_list)
```

no more queryset error

Comment: this code force the whole queryset to be evaluated, loading the whole table in memory. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy